# From holes in the image of peculiar functions to new perspective on the Riemann Hypothesis

Tags: cv.complex-variables, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function, riemann-hypothesis

I am working with the Dirichlet eta function $\eta(z)$, with $z=\sigma+it$, $\sigma > \frac{1}{2}$, and $t>0$. Let us define
$$\eta_n(z,\gamma)= \sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k+1}\lambda_k^{-\sigma} e^{-it\log k},$$
with $\lambda_2=\gamma>0$, and $\lambda_k=k$ if $k\neq 2$. Clearly, this is the Dirichlet eta function if $n=\infty$ and $\gamma=2$. For convenience and compatibility with my research, I use the notation $\beta=1/\gamma$. I plotted a few orbits, corresponding to various values of $n,\sigma, \beta$. These are standard scatterplots representing the function in the complex plane, as a function of $t$.

[image]

Clearly, in the pictured examples, there is a "hole", and its center is on the X-axis (real axis). If you plot the infinite orbit for all $t>0$ (not just $0<t<20000$) the hole may get reduced to a single point (its center) or nothing (an empty set), or may have a radius $\rho>0$. Note that in general, there is no hole at all; examples with a hole are uncommon. The size of the hole, and its center, depends on $\sigma$ and $\beta$. The higher $\sigma$ or $\beta$, the easier. Also if you increase $n$ or reduce $\sigma$ from $1.5$ to (say) $0.65$, the hole moves to the left on the X-axis, in general. The hole exists and is also visible if $\beta=0.5,
n=\infty$, corresponding to the Dirichlet eta function.

The potential questions associated with these holes range from trivial (high school if $n=2$ or $3$, or $\sigma>2$) to extremely hard and well beyond a simple question. I have chosen to ask one that is a first important stepping stone for future research: not trivial, but I believe easy enough to be of interest to the readers.

**Question**

Among the four above plots, which one(s) have a hole of radius $\rho>0$ as $t\rightarrow\infty$? I don't have an answer, and you can pick up the easiest one.

**Connection to Riemann Hypothesis**

First we may replace $\eta_n(z,\gamma)$ by a scaled version, say $\sqrt{t}\cdot(\eta_n(z,\gamma)-z_0)$, to magnify the hole, in the hope that it does not shrink to a single point as $t\rightarrow\infty$. Here $z_0$ is the center of the hole. In dynamical systems, the hole is referred to as basin of repulsion.

Then the big question is: how far you can go when reducing $\sigma$ from $1.5$ to (say) $0.6$, and $\beta$ from $2.0$ to (say) $0.5$. If $\beta$ can be reduced to $0.5$ while preserving the hole, for some $0.5<\sigma<1$, we would be half-way done with RH.

To finish RH, one would have to show that as $\beta\rightarrow 0.5$ and $n\rightarrow\infty$, the hole moves to the left so that at the end, it encompasses (and indeed coincides with) the origin. If $\zeta(z)$ has some unexpected root that disproves RH, then the hole, in that case, will become an empty set as soon as $t$ reaches the imaginary part of that unfortunate root.

**Update**

The plot below is the Dirichlet eta function (orbit) for $\sigma=0.75$. The leftmost black dot on the horizontal (real) axis is the origin, the right one is $(1,0)$. If you look at this finite portion of the orbit, the center of the hole is on the right side of the origin. Yet the origin is also inside the hole (if it was not, we could potentially have unexpected roots violating RH). MathOverflow only allows you to upload files up to 2MB, so this is just one frame in the first part of the video (the last frames are too large, and the video itself far too large). You can see the full video [here](https://youtu.be/wp4_bryCutU).

A few comments:

- It looks like the orbit (as $t$ increases) progresses clockwise at all time.
- On the left side of the hole, the curvature points towards the center
  of the hole, thus to the right.
- Strong curvature occurs in specific areas, typically close to the
  center of the hole, but never far away.
- If $\sigma=0.5$ (not shown here), the rotation is always clockwise.
- The whole system exhibits considerable stability in its chaotic
  trajectory: there are forces [terms in the $\eta(z)$ series] acting
  against each other to kind of balance out nicely, preventing the
  orbit from getting into the hole. Yet if you modify even very slightly these terms, you lose the hole.

[image]

**Main takeaways**

I try to bring some leeway to (hopefully) facilitate the investigation of RH. The center of the hole, for $\sigma=0.75$ and $0<t<T$ with $T=200$, is not the origin, but rather $z_0=(c,0)$ with $c\approx 0.15$. Rescaling $\eta(z)$, replacing it by (say) $\sqrt{t}(\eta(z)-z_0)$ could help, by preventing the hole from shrinking to a singleton as $T\rightarrow\infty$. This may not be helpful if the universality property of $\eta$ still leads to a singleton no matter how fast-increasing the scaling factor is.

Note that $c$ depends on $\sigma$ and $t$. Higher values of $T$ can drive $c$ further away from zero (more on the right on the X axis), making the problem more complicated. But the hole is larger when $\sigma$ is larger: in the end, this makes things easier when $\sigma$ is larger. Also using $\beta>0.5$ makes things easier (bigger hole), but then you need to get $\beta\rightarrow 0.5$ to finalize RH.

In the end, RH states that no matter what happens, the origin stays in the hole as $T\rightarrow\infty$, if $0.5<\sigma<1$. Note that if $\sigma=0.5$, the hole is replaced by a singleton (the origin) and turned into an attraction rather than a repulsion point. Yet, there is this: any time the orbit gets too close to the origin, it either bounces back (gets deflated, moving away) or go straight through the hole. If you plot the distance $d(t)$ to the origin as a function of $t$, the derivative of $d(t)$ is discontinuous if and only if $t$ corresponds to a non-trivial root.

Some computation for $\sigma=0.75$ and $T=200$: the radius of the hole (if $c=0.15$) is about $0.23$. If you erroneously assumes that the origin is the center of the hole $(c=0)$ the radius shrinks to $0.14$, still clearly strictly larger than zero.

Finally, I posted a new video with three orbits ($0.5, 0.75, 1.25$), [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9IdkvifRFgU).

Comment: Another video which better shows the progress of the orbit can be found here: https://youtu.be/xwFT8RmF5Mk

Comment: Another way to gain more insights is as follows: play with finite values of $n$. Remove some of the terms in the first formula. Depending on which ones you choose to remove, the hole may be there (with varying sizes and center locations), or not. It shows, at some intuitive level, how the various $\log k$ in the sine/cosine functions, interact. These interactions do not seem random: whether the $k$'s that you keep are all co-primes or not, seem to have an impact on the existence of the hole.

Comment: Finally, thanks to formula such as $\cos(a+b)=\cos a \cos b - \sin a \sin b$ and $a^\sigma b^\sigma=(ab)^\sigma$, in the end $\eta(z)$ is a combination of sums/factors such as $\cos(t\log k)/k^\sigma$, where $k$ is prime. Not sure if this fact leads to anything of interest, but it shows the connection to primes, in a different way than the Euler product does..